# Can you have two "die" functions simultaneously?

Tags: php

I am creating a website where people can comment about companies they have dealt with. When a web user enters his comments and submits, those comments will be stored in a database. He will then be asked one of two questions: does he want to make another comment about another company, OR does he want to log out. You will see below, next to the "die" function, that the user is being given the option to make another comment. But my problem is, how do I make another "die" statement which logs him out? The logout page is called "logout.php". The "die" statement that logs him out would be something like:

die("I wish to log out now "
                 . "a href = 'logout.php' → Please log me out!/a");

(I am ignoring the HTML tags.)

My problem is that when I place the "die" function above right below the first "die" function (so that the user would be able to see TWO hyperlinks, one if he wants to make another comment and the other if he simply wants to log out), I can only see the FIRST hyperlink: --> Make Another Comment. I do NOT see the hyperlink which will enable the user to logout. I don't understand this. Could someone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<style>
body {background-color:green}
h1 {color:blue}
/* Plenty of CSS goes in here */
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
   require_once 'connect.php';

   include "display.php";

 // plenty of isset functions go in here

   else if(isset($_POST['company']))
   {
         $company = $_POST['company'];
         $username = $username;
         $commentary = $_POST['commentary'];

         // write comment to data base
        mysqli_query($dbcon,"INSERT INTO `mycomments`  (`username`, 
     `company`, `commentary`) VALUES ('$username',
     '$company', '$commentary')");

        mysqli_close($dbcon);

         die("Your comments will be seen by: $company </br>"
             . "<a href = 'recordedcomments.php'> &rarr; Make another       
      comment!</a>");

   }

 else {


    ?>


<h1>Which other company do you want to make a comment about?</h1>
<div id="form">
            <form method="post" action="somefilename.php">
   <!--Plenty of HTML goes in here-->
            </form>
        </div>

<script type='text/javascript'....></script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You realise that using die() will terminate the script execution, so that none of the rest of your following markup will be rendered, incliding the closing body and html tags

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't how you should be using `die`. The whole point of it is that it **stops further execution of your script**.

Consider using `echo` instead.